# delete unnecessary data from NSArray

Tags: xcode, cocoa, filter, nsarray

i have a NSArray with a lot of Data coming from JSON.
This is from my JSON Database

```
    {
          "ID":"6173",
          "Name":"Heuriger Familie Haller",
          "BeschreibungApp":"Heuriger Familie Haller, 2102 Bisamberg",
          "Link":"http:\/\/heurigenapp.nocache.gugler.at\/app.php?id=6173",
          "Icon":"Weintraube",
          "Latitude":"48.33284",
          "Longitude":"16.36383",
          "Altitude":"0",
          "Ort":"Bisamberg"
   }
```

I have 20 objects like this. And all this i have in a NSArray.
But i want an Array only with "Ort" so i don't need most of the information.

can i do it like this:

```
newsTown = [news valueForKey:@"Ort"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, KVC to the rescue :D

you want to follow a KeyPath:

`Array *new = [array valueForKeyPath:@"Ort"];`

ASSUMING news is your NSArray of the JSON dics

Comment: But wehn i came to the line where stands: cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ort"]; the app crashes. Do you why this is so?

Comment: are you using ARC? If not retain the new array :) `Array *new = [[array valueForKeyPath:@"Ort"] retain];`

Comment: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'retain'

Comment: that's why I said: if you are not using arc ;P

Comment: anyways it is a simply problem: you only save the "Ort" in the new array -- so no more dicts. just strings :) -- so: `cell.textLabel.text = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: Thank you a lot. And do you also have an idea how i can double entries (some towns twice in the array) delete from the array?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do:

```
NSArray * newsTownArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject: [news valueForKey: @"Ort"]];
```

Comment: wastes an intermediate array and he has many news objects in an array of news objects so this wouldn't work this way :)

Comment: @Daij-Djan: He can also do it as an mutable array and add a new object to it for each of the 20 objects, but in any event, thanks for the downvote!

Comment: this doesn't work the way you wrote it .. you create an array WITH the value of the key "Ort" (which the array won't have) so you will actually get a nil pointer exception AFAICS => thats why I took the liberty to down vote.

Comment: (I revoked my vote .. ppl tend to take it personally... though I never mean it that way )